# for every positive integer $k$, there exists an integer $x$ such that $kx^2-1$ is quadratic residue (mod $p$)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

> Prove that for every positive integer $k$, there exists an integer $x$ such that $kx^2-1$ is quadratic residue (mod $p$)

I don't think this statement is true since $k$ the sequence $k \cdot 1^2-1,k \cdot 2^2-1 , \cdots , k \cdot \left( \frac{p-1}{2} \right)^2-1$ are congruent to $r_1,r_2, \cdots , r_{(p-1)/2}$ modulo $p$ where as $r_i$ are quadratic residue (mod $p$) for some $k$.

My question: Is the statement above true ? If not then for what $k$ it's true ?

Comment: If $k$ is a multiple of $p$, and $p$ (presumably a prime) is $\equiv3\pmod4$, then this never happens. If $p\nmid k$ the usual counting argument (done many times on our site) works: there are $(p+1)/2$ distinct residue classes of the form $kx^2-1$, and $(p+1)/2$ distinct residue classes of the form $y^2$. Because there are only $p$ residue classes altogether, the two sets must intersect non-trivially. If $p\mid k$ and $p\equiv1\pmod4$, then $-1$ is a quadratic residue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Jyrki Lahtonen.